# Replace() question mark in image dimensions string from Shell

Tags: excel, vba, shell, windows-7

I'm trying to get the height of a bitmap by using the Shell object in VBA.

Here is the relevant portion of code (`bmp` is a member of a custom class, and `.Width` is a property defined as an Integer.)

```
Set objImg = objShell.Namespace(subfs(sf)).ParseName(bmp.Name)
tmpDim = objShell.Namespace(subfs(sf)).GetDetailsOf(objImg, 162)
tmpDim = Replace(tmpDim, "?", "")
tmpDim = Replace(tmpDim, " pixels", "")
bmp.Width = CInt(tmpDim)
```

I'm getting a Type Mismatch error on the last line because the value of tmpDim is `?754`. For reference, the value of tmpDim after the second line is `?754 pixels`.

I have a step to replace the `?` with an empty string, but it does not work. How can I get rid of the question mark character?

Comment: It's probably "?" as in "this is a non printable character" rather than a question mark, Check its ascii value: `asc(left(tmpDim,1))` & use that in the replace (`chr$(itsasciivalue)`)

Comment: @AlexK. I tried that. It was character 63, which is the question mark.

Comment: Does it work for the "pixels" replace?

Comment: Yes, by the last line the value is `?754`.

Comment: Weird. Strip if off based on position? `if not isnumeric(left$(tmpDim,1)) then tmpDim = mid$(tmpDim,2)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had moved away from that kind of solution (minus the crucial `If Not IsNumeric` part) because the dimensions gathered on my coworker's Windows XP machine did not have the question mark. If you post that as an answer, you will get at least an upvote from me. I'm still holding out for an explanation of why this happens, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question mark you are seeing is not actually a question mark. The Asc() function will return a value of 63, but AscW() will probably return 8206, the unicode left-to-right mark.

I believe VBA stores strings using two-byte wide characters. The Asc function will only return a value of 0-255 and appears to return 63 for anything outside that range.

This is why your `Replace(tmpDim, "?", "")` doesn't work.
You're trying the equivilent of

```
Replace(tmpDim, Chr(63), "")
```

You need

```
Replace(tmpDim, ChrW(8206), "")
```

(Assuming the ? is the left-to-right mark, which in my testing it is)

Comment: Very good explanation of the underlying problem -- I was afraid this one had fallen into the unsolved mysteries category. Hopefully this will help someone else down the line. Thanks!