# VBA: How to remove non-printable characters from data

Tags: string, vba, replace, ms-access-2007

I need to remove programmatically non printable characters such as:

tabs - char(9)
line breaks - char(10)
carriage return - char(13)
data link escape - char(16)

I started a generic function that will be called from the lost_focus event of the ms access form field.

I have not figured out how to identify when the string contains the unwanted characters.

```
    Function RemoveNonPrintableCharacters(ByVal TextData) As String

        Dim dirtyString As String
        Dim cleanString As String
        Dim iPosition As Integer

        If IsNull(TextData) Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        dirtyString = TextData
        cleanString = ""

        For iPosition = 1 To Len(dirtyString)
            Select Case Asc(Mid(dirtyString, iPosition, 1))
                Case 9    ' Char(9)
                Case 10   ' Char(10)
                Case 13   ' Char(13)
                Case 16   ' Char(16)
                Case Else ' Add character to clean field.
                    cleanString = cleanString & Mid(dirtyString, iPosition, 1)
            End Select
        Next

        RemoveNonPrintableCharacters = cleanString

    End Function
```

These are 2 strings I have been using whilst testing:

```
This line,    has       multiple,     tabs       that   need to be removed


This line, has multiple,     
line
breaks
that
need to be removed

This line,    has       multiple,     tabs       that   need to be removed
And
Also contains
multiple,     
line
breaks
that
need to be  removed
```

Comment: "I have not figured out how to identify when the string contains the unwanted characters."  Are you wanting to identify strings that are "dirty" simply to avoid wasting time performing unnecessary processing within your function?

Comment: I want to clean the string before it gets sent to the database.

Comment: Consider that any way of "identifying when the string contains unwanted characters" will involve iterating through the characters one by one, whether it's done by you directly or by some other built-in function. Is your goal to speed up the process?

Comment: I would definitely like to have a fast processing, but my main goal is to avoid unwanted data into the database. These are MS Access forms that uses sometimes copy & paste text; sometimes these lines of text contain tabs, line breaks that make it to the database. I am adding a function call on the event Lost_Focus for each field that allows pasting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the top google result when I search for a quick function to use, I've had a good old google but nothing that solves my issue fully has really come up.

The main issue is that all of these functions touch the original string even if there's no issue. Which slows stuff down.

I've rewritten it so that only amends if bad character, also expanded to all non-printable characters and characters beyond standard ascii.

```
Public Function Clean_NonPrintableCharacters(Str As String) As String

    'Removes non-printable characters from a string

    Dim cleanString As String
    Dim i As Integer

    cleanString = Str

    For i = Len(cleanString) To 1 Step -1
        'Debug.Print Asc(Mid(Str, i, 1))

        Select Case Asc(Mid(Str, i, 1))
            Case 1 To 31, Is >= 127
                'Bad stuff
                'https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/ascii-codes-overview-of-all-characters-on-the-ascii-table/
                cleanString = Left(cleanString, i - 1) & Mid(cleanString, i + 1)

            Case Else
                'Keep

        End Select
    Next i

    Clean_NonPrintableCharacters = cleanString

End Function
```

Comment: I found I could get rid of some additional problems by running the For loop a second time with Ascw() instead of Asc().  See the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110431/replace-question-mark-in-image-dimensions-string-from-shell

Comment: Many years late but I'd recommend adding Case 0 as part of the values that should be discarded.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = Chr(09) & "Cat" & Chr(10) & vbcrlf

A = Replace(A, Chr(10))
A = Replace(A, Chr(13))
A = Replace(A, Chr(09))

Msgbox A
```

This is how one normally does it.

Your code is creating a lot of implicit variables.

Answer (score 2):

When Unicode characters appear, the codes presented here should be modified. My proposal includes unrecognized characters by the program:

```
Public Function Clean_NonPrintableCharacters(Str As String) As String

    'Removes non-printable characters from a string

    Dim cleanString As String
    Dim i As Integer

    cleanString = Str
    
    For i = Len(cleanString) To 1 Step -1

        If Chr(Asc(Mid(cleanString, i, 1))) <> Mid(cleanString, i, 1) Then
        cleanString = Left(cleanString, i - 1) & Mid(cleanString, i + 1)
        End If
        
    Next i

    Clean_NonPrintableCharacters = WorksheetFunction.Clean(cleanString)

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Function RemoveNonPrintableCharacters(ByVal TextData) As String

    Dim dirtyString As String
    Dim cleanString As String
    Dim iPosition As Integer

    If IsNull(TextData) Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    dirtyString = TextData
    cleanString = ""

    For iPosition = 1 To Len(dirtyString)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(dirtyString, iPosition, 1))
            Case 9, 10, 13, 16
                cleanString = cleanString & " "
                Case Else
                cleanString = cleanString & Mid(dirtyString, iPosition, 1)
        End Select
    Next

    RemoveNonPrintableCharacters = cleanString

End Function
```

Comment: All that concatenation is going to be slooowww. To replace the unwanted chars with spaces in place, use the Mid$ statement. Or convert to a byte array, scan that, and convert back.

Comment: yep, good point.  The solution was more in line with his own solution where he identified a method for catching the characters he wanted to replace but wasn't doing anything with them.

Comment: Hi RyanL, how can i also check for lines like this one: "this line,    has       multiple,     spaces      in between     words    that   need to be removed" so that there is only one space between each word?

Comment: Also, if you can show me a more efficient way of doing this with a function, I would welcome that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if this should be much simpler, using the Excel Clean function.  The following also works:

```
myString = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & tRow).Value 
myString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(myString)
```

You can also use other normal and home-grown Excel functions:

```
myString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(myString)
```

Still haven't gotten the Substitute function to work in this way, but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

'first you need to find a character

YourStr = "Bla bla bla..."

if instr(YourStr, chr(10)) > 0 then

```
NewStr = Replace(YourStr, Chr(10),"")
```

end  if

Answer (score 0):

I'm replacing non-printable characters with a space character chr(32) but you can alter this to suit your needs.

```
Function RemoveNonPrintableCharacters(ByVal TextData) As String
Dim sClean$

sClean = Replace(TextData, Chr(9), Chr(32))
sClean = Replace(sClean, Chr(10), Chr(32))
sClean = Replace(sClean, Chr(13), Chr(32))
sClean = Replace(sClean, Chr(16), Chr(32))

RemoveNonPrintableCharacters = sClean

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This works to remove Non-printing Characters from the right side of the string only and do not replace the characters with spaces.

```
Function fRemoveNonPrintableCharacters(ByVal TextData) As String
Dim dirtyString As String
Dim cleanString As String
Dim iPosition As Integer

If IsNull(TextData) Then
    Exit Function
End If

dirtyString = TextData
cleanString = ""

For iPosition = Len(dirtyString) To 1 Step -1
    Select Case Asc(Mid(dirtyString, iPosition, 1))
        Case 9, 10, 13, 16, 32, 160
            cleanString = cleanString
            Case Else
            cleanString = Left(dirtyString, iPosition)
            Exit For

    End Select
Next

fRemoveNonPrintableCharacters = cleanString

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by RegEx (add MS VBScript Regular Expression in Tools - References in VBE):

```
Function NormalString(text As String, Optional filler = vbNullString) As String
    Dim re As New RegExp
    With re
        .Pattern = "([\x00-\x1F\xA0])"
        .Global = True
        text = .Replace(text, filler)
    End With
    NormalString = text
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are special characters, then replace them with spaces

```
If InStr(TextData, Chr(9)) > 0 Then TextData = Replace(TextData, Chr(9), Chr(32))
If InStr(TextData, Chr(10)) > 0 Then TextData = Replace(TextData, Chr(10), Chr(32))
If InStr(TextData, Chr(13)) > 0 Then TextData = Replace(TextData, Chr(13), Chr(32))
If InStr(TextData, Chr(16)) > 0 Then TextData = Replace(TextData, Chr(16), Chr(32))
```