# VBA convert unusual string to Date

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I wanted to scrape data from yahoo as an excercise and then make a graph from it. I encountered a problem where when I scrape the dates, they are in a rather weird format:

`?10? ?Aug?, ?2020`

The question marks in the string are not realy question marks, they are some characters unknown to me, so I cannot remove them with Replace().

Then, when I try to use CDate() to convert this to Date format, the code crashed on "Type mismatch" error.

What I would need is to either find a way to find out what those characters are in order to remove them with Replace(), or to somehow convert even this weird format to a Date.
Alternatively, somehow improving the scraping procedure - so far I've been using for example

```
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)")(3).innerText
```

to get the data - would also solve this problem.

If anyone wanted to try to scrape it, too an example url:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LAC/history?period1=1469404800&period2=1627171200&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d&includeAdjustedClose=true
```

An example of my code follows:

```
DateString = doc.getElementsByClassName("Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)")(j).innerText
LeftDateString = Clean_NonPrintableCharacters(DateString)
Worksheets("Stock_data").Range("A2").Value = CDate(LeftDateString)
```

Comment: Is your desired format just `10 Aug, 2020`? What is the first represented as `01`? Just thinking perhaps just take the middle two digits of the first break, etc...

Comment: have you tried the `=CODE("textValue")` function to get the numeric value?  You can then use that with Replace.

Comment: @BruceWayne My desired format is whatever fits into CDate(), honestly

Comment: Remove the non-printable characters from your string before passing to any date functions - see great example function at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882525/vba-how-to-remove-non-printable-characters-from-data

Comment: @dbmitch That sounds like a great idea, however, the function literally did nothing to the string I gave it... No idea what that means or what those characters are

Comment: @JirkaČep - where is your code? You need to assign the innerText to a variable and then pass that variable to the code. Are you using Debug.Print to show the string? If so, try using Debug.Print ASC(strInnerText) to get the character code for the first letter - you can also try AscB to get the first byte value

Comment: @dbmitch added my code, I used the cleaning function from your link

Comment: So what do you get when you use Debug.Print ASC(DateString) in your error trapping code

Comment: It says 63, which is a question mark... But apparently its not, I already tried ```Replace(DateString, "?", vbNullString)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regexp:

```vb
Function GetDate(txt)
    ' set a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5' in Tools->References VBE menu
    Dim re As New RegExp, retval(0 To 2), patterns, i, result
    patterns = Array("\b\d\d\b", "\b[a-zA-Z]+\b", "\b\d{4}\b")
    For i = 0 To 2
        re.Pattern = patterns(i)
        Set result = re.Execute(txt)
        If result Is Nothing Then Exit Function 'If no day, month or year is found, GetDate() returns ""
        retval(i) = result(0)
    Next
    
    GetDate = Join(retval)
End Function

Sub Usage()
    For Each txt In Array("?10? ?Aug?, ?2020", "Jul 13, 2020", "2021, March?, 18?")
        Debug.Print GetDate(txt)
    Next
End Sub
```

Prints:

```
10 Aug 2020
13 Jul 2020
18 March 2021
```

### Edit 2

```vb
Function GetDate2(txt)
    ' set a reference to 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5' in Tools->References VBE menu
    Static re As RegExp, months As Collection
    Dim result
    
    If re Is Nothing Then   'do it once
        Set re = New RegExp
        re.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
        re.Global = True
        Set months = New Collection
        cnt = 1
        For Each m In Split("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec", ",")
            months.Add cnt, m
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Next
    End If
    
    result = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(re.Replace(txt, " ")))
    For i = 0 To UBound(result)
        If Not IsNumeric(result(i)) Then
            result(i) = Left(LCase(result(i)), 3)
            On Error Resume Next
            result(i) = months(result(i))
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next
    result = Join(result)
    If IsDate(result) Then GetDate2 = CDate(result)
End Function

Sub Usage2()
    For Each txt In Array("?10? ?Aug?, ?2020", "Jul 13, 2020", "2021, March?, 18?", _
                          "01/12/2021", "04.18.2020", "15 10 20")
        Debug.Print GetDate2(txt)
    Next
End Sub
```

Prints:

```
10.08.2020 
13.07.2020 
18.03.2021 
01.12.2021 
18.04.2020 
15.10.2020
```

Note. The order of the dd and mm may be vary

Comment: I enabled the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5 but still it gives me a "Invalid procedure call or argument. txt argument is "Jul 13, 2020" at the moment (sometimes it scrapes the date without the ? signs, not sure why).

Comment: Edited. The function handles dates with any order of day, month and year, regardless of `?`

Comment: This works! It transforms the string into a normal string, but then, some of the entries just refuse to be coerced into a correct date format. Some of them are in the form of mm-dd-yy instead and reduse to be switched, any idea why that might be? I was under the impression that CDate should convert everythin into the same format

Comment: See Edit2 option

Comment: Wow the Edit2 solution works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like so.  I've used your ? as question marks for this example, i assumed they were all the same wierd character.  This outputs

`10 Aug 2020`

```
Sub d()

Dim d As String

d = "?10? ?Aug?, ?2020"
d = Replace(Replace(d, Chr(Asc(Left(d, 1))), vbNullString), ",", vbNullString)

Debug.Print d

End Sub
```

Comment: That, very surprisingly, did not remove even the leftmost character, no idea why

Comment: Also worth mentioning, sometimes, the scraper gets a "clean" string (10 Aug 2020) and sometimes it doesnt. I havent been able to replicate the scraping state it reliably

Answer (score 0):

you could loop though each char in the string and check its ascii values and create your date string from that.  Example

```
Sub GetTheDate(sDate As String)
'97 - 122: lower case Ascii values
Dim i As Integer
Dim strDate As String

'loop through each char
For i = 1 To Len(sDate)
    'check to see if it is numeric
    If IsNumeric(Mid(sDate, i, 1)) Then
        'numeric so add it to the string
        strDate = strDate & Mid(sDate, i, 1)
    Else
        'check to see if it is a char a-z
        If Asc(LCase(Mid(sDate, i, 1))) >= 97 And Asc(LCase(Mid(sDate, i, 1))) <= 122 Then
            'it is an a char from a-z so add it to string
            strDate = strDate & Mid(sDate, i, 1)
        Else
            'chekc for a space and add a comma - this sets up being able to use cdate()
            If Mid(sDate, i, 1) = " " Then
                strDate = strDate & ","
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i
'convert it and print it
Debug.Print CDate(strDate)
End Sub
```