# VBA to convert Excel cells "date like" values into the date format issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of dates in the column. All the cells are date values in fact, but they are not in Excel date format and I cannot convert them into the dates. All the dates are modification of the system Long date format, but not the standard system Long date format. Actually they correspond to the following format template:

```
"[$-uk-UA-x-genlower]d mmmm yyyy" (or "[$-FC22]dd mmmm yyyy")
```

Such values look like this: “14 лип**ня** 2021”, but Excel doesn’t treat them like dates.
Conventional Excel VBA functions `DateValue` and `CDate` do not work (I receive “type mismatch” error).
At the same time they work fine with the values which correspond to this format template (standard system Long date format):

```
"d mmmm yyyy"
```

Such values look like this: “14 лип**ень** 2021”
I cannot convert my cell values into standard system Long date format.
If I do this:

```
Dim LstrDate As String
Dim LDate As Date
    LstrDate = "14 липня 2021"
    Debug.Print IsDate(LstrDate)
    LDate = CDate(LstrDate)
```

I receive: False and Type mismatch error.
If I had this: `LstrDate = "14 липень 2021"`
I would receive True and success. But I do not want to modify hundreds of cells by hands.
The question is: is there any way to convert cell values which corresponds to `"[$-uk-UA-x-genlower]d mmmm yyyy"` template into Excel date format and treat them like dates?
I am looking for a function which can convert values in the cells into date-type format like `CDate` or for a way to make existing functions `CDate` or `DateValue` to work with this type of data.

P.S. This is not an issue of a language. It can be set in any other language with formatCode16 attribute.
`.NumberFormat` doesn’t change anything.
It’s also funny, but if I have date-type cell value, I can change its format using `.NumberFormat` as I want: from `“dd.mm.yyyy”` to `"[$-uk-UA-x-genlower]d mmmm yyyy"` and back and it works.

Comment: Yesterday I wrote a solution to a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68549589/15035314. You might find Edit 2 option helpful

Comment: I've changed slightly your function (pattern - to Cyrillic letters and names of months to Ukrainian names of months (3 letters only)) and it really works. Of course it is not a sophisticated build-in Excel function, it's just more a kind of work-around, but it works! Thank you.

Comment: I've tested your function a little bit more. The problem is with months, which have Ukrainian "і" in the name. There is a problem here: `re.Replace(txt, " ")` I don't know why, but it cuts "і"-letter. And we receive a problem with recognition of 2 months, which have "і" in the name.

Comment: One option is to Replace() unhandy symbols before processing

Comment: It's ok, but Replace () doesn't see Ukrainian "i" at all.  When I try `txt = Replace(txt, "і", "i")` (1-st Ukrainian, 2-nd English), it does nothing. Of course it shouldn't be English "i", but it looks like VBA doesn't understand special national letters/ symbols.

Comment: Use ascii or unicode symbol code - chr(...) or chrw(...). Smth like `txt = Replace(txt, chrw(1110), "i")` (not tested)

Comment: It works, thank you again. If to use Chr, the symbol code is 179. And I had to change a Pattern to "[^a-zA-Zа-яА-я0-9]". Now it works perfect.